# entity Framework : comparing query's performance

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using entity framework , and I have several cases where I should run a query than return some master rows , and after I use these master rows and the related children too in my report.

I want to know which of these methods have the better performance : ( or is there any other better method ??? )

Method1: (the children entities are loaded later , using lazy loading)

```
Dim lista as IQueryable(Of MyObj) = (From t In context.MyObjs Where(..condition..) select t).Tolist
```

Method2:

```
Dim lista as IQueryable(Of MyObj) = (From t In context.MyObjs Where(..condition..) _
            .Include(Function(t2) t2.Childs1) _
             .Include(Function(t2) t2.Childs2) _
             .Include(Function(t2) t2.Childs2.Child22) _
              .Include(Function(t2) t2.Childs1.Childs11) _
              .Include(Function(t2) t2.Childs1.Childs12) _
              Select t).ToList
```

Method3:

```
Dim lista as IQueryable(Of MyObj)
Dim lst= (From t2 In context.MyObjs Where(..condition..) Select New with _
       {    .Parent=t2
            .ch1=t2.Childs1 _
             .ch2=t2.Childs2 _
             .ch21=t2.Childs2.Child21) _
             .ch11=t2.Childs1.Childs11) _
              .ch12= t2.Childs1.Childs12 _
              ).ToList
 lista=lst.Select(Function(t2) t2.parent)
```

I noticed that the first method cause the report to open very slow. Also I read somewhere that Include() cause repeat of master rows?

But anyway I want an opinion in general for the three methods.

Thank you !

Comment: call all 3 and analyze them via this profiler: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof. It tells you how long they run and give you tips.

Comment: I want more to understand in general than to take a result for a specific case like this. So in general , according to how these 3 methods works , what is supposed to be with more performance : Lazyloading , Include() or using an anonymous type ?